# Converting an array's type to Mongoose Model

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose-schema

In nodejs post route I saved mongoose model objects into an array now I want to to save that array to mongodb, in order to do this I need to invoke array.save() method which is mongoose built in method. To do this I need to convert this array to Mongoose model type that is **Form** in this case. Please tell how to apply this conversion, or do I need any other solution?
**Mongoose schema is:**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;    

var formSchema = new Schema({    
    controlType: {type: String, required: true},   
    label: {type: String, required: true},
    required: {type: Boolean}, 
    placeholder: {type: String},   
    options: [String],    //to store options for select or radio input
} ,  {collection: 'inputForm'});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Form', formSchema);
```

**NodeJS post route:**

```
router.post('/userform', function (req, res, next) {

    var form = [];    
    for (var key in req.body) {
        if (req.body.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            var formObj = new Form({
                controlType: req.body[key].controlType,
                label: req.body[key].label,
                required: req.body[key].required,
                placeholder: req.body[key].placeholder,
                options: req.body[key].options
            });                        
        }
        form.push(formObj);        
    }
    console.log('type of form 0528');
    console.log(typeof(form));

    form.save(function(err, result) { // here is the issue, this line is not working because form is not type of mongoose model
        if (err) {
            return res.status(500).json({
                title: 'An error occurred in form api 0528',
                error: err
            });
        }
        res.status(201).json({
            message: 'Form created',
            obj: result
        });
    });    
});

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Model.create** can take an array of objects to create multiple documents.

So you could build an array of objects rather than model instances and then pass that array to **Form.create**:

```
var formArr = []

for (var key in req.body) {

  if (req.body.hasOwnProperty(key)) {

    var formObj = {
      controlType: req.body[key].controlType,
      label: req.body[key].label,
      required: req.body[key].required,
      placeholder: req.body[key].placeholder,
      options: req.body[key].options
    }

    formArr.push(formObj)

  }

}

Form.create(formArr, function(err, results) {

  ...

})
```

---

If you want to save an array of objects  in a single document, then try using a nested schema:

```
var controlSchema = new Schema({    
  controlType: {type: String, required: true},   
  label: {type: String, required: true},
  required: {type: Boolean}, 
  placeholder: {type: String},   
  options: [String]
}, {collection: 'inputForm'})

var formSchema = new Schema({    
  controls: [controlSchema]
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Form', formSchema)
```

...and then save the array as the **controls** field in a new document like this:

```
var controlsArr = []

for (var key in req.body) {

  if (req.body.hasOwnProperty(key)) {

    var controlObj = {
      controlType: req.body[key].controlType,
      label: req.body[key].label,
      required: req.body[key].required,
      placeholder: req.body[key].placeholder,
      options: req.body[key].options
    }

    controlsArr.push(controlObj)

  }

}

var form = new Form({
  controls: controlsArr
})

form.save(function(err, result) {

  ...

})
```

Comment: but I want to store it as one document that contains an array of objects, not in separate documents. @Steve Holgado

Comment: So you want one document with an array of **Form** sub-documents? In that case, you will need a schema with an array field which contains objects like the one you have.

Comment: I have updated my answer with a solution using nested schemas to save the array to a single document. I hope this helps.

Comment: yes it worked, thanks alot. I gained good piece of knowledge from your answer.

Comment: Would you please help me further about how to implement get route to read this record?

Comment: You can use **Form.findOne()** with a query to find the document, or **Form.findById()** if you know the _id of the document. Otherwise you can use **Form.find({}, function(err, docs) { ... })** to find all documents and then process the returned docs to find the one you want to return in your route response.

Comment: Got it, Thanks alot